# Tesseract OCR (C++) Cannot Evaluate Output String

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, newline, tesseract

I am attempting to extract output string from an OpenCV Matrix window and evaluate it, but it seems to return something similar to "someString\n" rather "someString". This renders it difficult to compare knowing there are (x) amounts of white spaces.

I tried:

creating a char array that omits the white spaces (I am aware that I'm only evaluating 5 indexes)

```
std::string redef;
    char charArr[100] = {NULL};
    strcpy_s(charArr, str.c_str());

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (charArr[i] != ' ')
        {
            redef += charArr[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << "analyseAction ran:" << redef << "white-space?";
```

but the string returns something like

```
analyseAction ran:redefString
white-space?
```

Relevant code running in main function:

```
api->Recognize(0);
            outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
            analyseAction(outText);
```

bellow, just take note that the else statement runs since redef doesn't equal to "long" when long is shown visually in window.

```
void analyseAction(std::string str)
{
    std::string redef;
    char charArr[100] = {NULL};
    strcpy_s(charArr, str.c_str());

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (charArr[i] != ' ')
        {
            redef += charArr[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << "analyseAction ran:" << redef << "white-space?";

//alot of missing code, trying to show what is relevant

    if (redef == "long") //check if it has white space after long, seems like it new line's
    {
        //NOTE FOR FUTURE: Stop being lazy and make this a function of its own
        //BUY
        std::cout << "Long ran";
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) //no comma with first line so 0 element 
        {
            context += inData[i];
        }
        x = std::stoi(context);

        for (int i = a+1; i < a1; i++) 
        {
            context += inData[i]; 
        }
        y = std::stoi(context);

        simClick(x,y);
        //BUY CONFIRM
        for (int i = a1+1; i < b; i++) //starting from pipeline??
        {
            context += inData[i];
        }
        x = std::stoi(context);

        for (int i = b+1; i < b1; i++) //starting with comma? +1 to fix
        {
            context += inData[i];
        }
        y = std::stoi(context);

        simClick(x, y);

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "long does not match";
    }
}
```

I am confused, why does the string appear to new line? And how can I successfully evaluate the output? I am a noobie in C++ so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear... you are assessing a statement based on visual input of certain words getting recognized by the OCR?

Comment: yes. But the string tesseract api returns seems to include something similar to "\n" in strings.

Comment: Have you thought about assessing the first character or first few characters rather the entire string variable as an alternative?

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for why it's returning a string and a line break, I cannot answer that. But I can provide you an alternative system to what you are trying to accomplish. Remove your first for loop in the analyseAction function and in your if statement for "long" pass in... `if(charArr[0] == 'l') {//do stuff}` This does have a limit if you are assessing many words that start with "l", in this case assess the first two or three letters of the word so long they aren't less than 2 or 3 letter words. PS. this was written on mobile.